# How to create a hibernate Entity by name?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hierarchy with three Entity classes.

Base class is defined like this:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "`users`")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "`u_role`", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public abstract class User implements Serializable {
```

And two child classes:

```
@Entity(name = "Vendor")
@Table(name = "`vendors`")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Vendor extends User {
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Customer")
@Table(name = "`customers`")
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class Customer extends User {
```

All works great. Hibernate saves and reads objects as expected. But now I want to be able to create an object based on its type. Instead of using:

```
new Vendor()
```

I want to use a hibernate method that would return me an instance based on its type (discriminator) or entity name (e.g. - "Vendor"). Could someone tell me if there is such a method?

Comment: Do you want to create separate tables for Vendor and Customer? Is this what you want?

Comment: I do have separate tables for Vendor and Customer. As I said - it works just fine. I want to unify object creation process, so that I could create a new user by type only.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement an interface to all of that entity, then get new instance from its interface

```
    IEntity iEntity = new Entity();
    Class<? extends IEntity> aClass = iEntity.getClass();
    IEntity o;
    try {
        o = aClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you can also use string like `Class.forName("com.domain.Vendor");` then use `newInstance()`, you may also want to use [Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) to be able to invoke any class, something like this

```
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.domain.Vendor");
        Constructor<?> constructor = aClass.getConstructor();
        o = (IEntity) constructor.newInstance();
```